# why Javascript async/await code run async in parellel

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I saw this good article to introduce [async/await](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions) from Google.

However, I couldn't understand why these code run in parallel

```
async function parallel() {
  const wait1 = wait(500);
  const wait2 = wait(500);
  await wait1;
  await wait2;
  return "done!";
}
```

And this run in series

```
async function series() {
  await wait(500);
  await wait(500);
  return "done!";
}
```

Why is the key difference between these two methods ? 
In my opinion, both of them are await promise and should work the same result.

Here is my test code. Can run in browser console which support async/await.

```
function wait(){
    return new Promise((res)=>{setTimeout(()=>{res()}, 2000)})
}
async function parallel() {
  const wait1 = wait();
  const wait2 = wait();
  await wait1;
  await wait2;
  return "done!";
}
async function series() {
  await wait();
  await wait();
  return "done!";
}
parallel().then(res => console.log("parallel!"))
series().then(res => console.log("series!"))
```

====== 
Thanks for the answers.
But I still have some question. Why exact the async/await means?
In my knowledge, constructing Promise instance would execute directly.
Here is my test code

```
function wait(){
    return new Promise((res)=>{setTimeout(()=>{console.log("wait!");res();}, 2000)})
}

wait()
//Promise {<pending>}
//wait!

let w = wait()
//undefined
//wait!

let w = await wait()
//wait!
//undefined

async function test(){await wait()}
// undefined
test()
//Promise {<pending>}
//wait!
```

So why `const wait1 = wait(); inside parallel function` execute directly?
By the way, should I open another question to ask these question?

Comment: `await` expect the function to return a `Promise`. What's exactly in your `wait()` function?

Comment: I update my question. thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`await` doesn't cause the `Promise` or its `setTimeout()` to start, which seems to be what you're expecting. The call to `wait()` alone starts them immediately, whether there's an active `await` on the promise or not.

`await` only helps you know when the already on-going operation, tracked through the promise, has completed.

So, the difference is just due to when `wait()` is being called and starting each timeout:

- `parallel()` calls `wait()` back-to-back as quickly as the engine can get from one to the next, before either are `await`ed, so the 2 timeouts begin/end at nearly the same time.
- `series()` forces the 2nd `wait()` to not be called until after the 1st has completed, by having an `await` act in between them.

---

Regarding your edit, `async` and `await` are syntactic sugar. Using them, the engine will modify your function at runtime, inserting additional code needed to interact with the promises.

A (possible, but not precise) equivalent of `series()` without `await` and `async` might be:

```
function series() {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function () { return wait(500) })
    .then(function () { return wait(500) })
    .then(function () { return "done!"; });
}
```

And for `parallel()`:

```
function parallel() {
  const wait1 = wait(500);
  const wait2 = wait(500);

  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(wait1)
    .then(wait2)
    .then(function () { return "done!"; });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I am confused why `const wait1 = wait();` is not run directly?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

In `parallel()`, you call both methods *and then* `await` their results while in `series()` you `await` the result of the first `wait()` call before calling the second `wait()`.

> Why exact the async/await means? In my knowledge, constructing Promise instance would execute directly.

The `Promise` instance is returned immediately, i.e. synchronously. But the value of the `Promise` is evaluated asynchronously by calling the first parameter given to its constructor, a function usually called `resolve`. This is what you are `await`ing for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I am confused why `const wait1 = wait();` is not run directly?

Comment: @鄭元傑 I updated my answer. Have you read the [article about Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)? You should understand them fully before trying to understand `async`/`await`, which basically is just syntax sugar for `then()`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in `parallel`, both of the promises are scheduled right after each other.

In `series`, you wait for the first `wait` to **resolve** and *then* schedule the second `wait` to be called.

If we expand the methods we'd get something similar to:

```
function parallel() {
  const wait1 = wait();
  const wait2 = wait();
  // Both wait1 and wait2 timeouts are scheduled
  return wait1
    .then(() => wait2)
    .then(() => "done");
}

function series() {
  // The second wait happens _after_ the first has been *resolved*
  return wait()
    .then(() => wait())
    .then(() => "done");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I am confused why const wait1 = wait(); is not run directly?

Comment: When the `const` are instantiated, the promises are invoked so they both run. the code reads more like: start `wait1`, start `wait2`. when `wait1` is done, then return the result of `wait2`, then return `"done"`.